# Optimize a TCP/IP Socket Implementation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sockets, server, tcp

When connecting between two networked computers I have a ~40ms delay that I am trying to find the cause for. I am suspecting that the server application is the cause. I have checked using other software (i.e. Hercules) that the lag is tied to my software and I have considered transfering bits instead of strings. Congestion is probably not the cause, but maybe buffers and packet size - considering what I read in some early RFC docs. I think that the delay is due to the server and not the client, although this is just my guess. I programmed the client in ActionScript.

I am asking this question as Googling on the keywords TCP/IP and optimization returns results on TCP/IP configuration and not implementation. I am new to TCP/IP programming so I am hoping that the mistake will be easy to spot for a more advanced programmer.

The server app is programmed in VB.NET:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Shared remoteAddress As IPAddress = IPAddress.Any
Public Shared port As Int32 = 8080

Public Shared server As New TcpListener(remoteAddress, port)
Public client As TcpClient = Nothing

'....


While (True)
        Try

            Dim buffer(65536) As Byte

            Dim stuff As Integer = client.ReceiveBufferSize
            Console.WriteLine(stuff)

            networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, CInt(client.ReceiveBufferSize))

            Dim dataFromClient As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)

            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(dataFromClient.IndexOf("/") + 1, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\") - 1)


            If dataFromClient Like "/END\" Or dataFromClient Like "/STOP\" Then
                Console.WriteLine("STOP REQUESTED")

                Exit While
            End If

            SetMarker(dataFromClient)

            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient)

            Dim serverResponse As String = "Receiving marker #" + Convert.ToString(requestCount) + ":  " + dataFromClient
            Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            networkStream.Flush()
            Console.WriteLine(serverResponse)

        Catch illegalSyntax As System.ArgumentException
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Use correct syntax: /command\ Example: /S1\, /STOP\")
        Catch socketEx As SocketException
            Console.WriteLine(SocketError.Interrupted)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        requestCount = requestCount + 1
    End While
```

Comment: a) why are you concerned with 40ms? b) maybe there is other traffic on the network?

Comment: a) I have to send a trigger with ideally <1ms accuracy for scientific measurements. b) The computers are in the same room and share the same router/switch. Pinging computer 1 (client) from computer 2 (server) results in <1ms ping, so network load is an improbable cause. However, pinging computer 2 from 1 results in time-out, probably because ICMP is disabled - pinging localhost still works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:
Start with the smallest possible program, and measure performance. Slowly add in functionality and when performance reaches unacceptable levels, you will know which part of your program is taking the most time.

To that end, you try to put in some rudimentary profiling code to see where the most time being spent, being aware that extra code takes extra time to process.

In order to do this, perhaps use [Environment.TickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to measure time. I think there are some other high performance timers out there too.

That said, I'd start looking in a few places:

-You are allocating an array at the top of a tight loop. Why not declare the array outside the loop, then either clear it out, or more efficiently, keep track of how many array items are in use, and adjust the code accordingly.

-by re-assigning the string variable back to itself, you are causing a whole new string to be allocated. Rather than reassigning the substring, perhaps do a String.contains to check for your condition

-Like is a pattern matching keyword. Try to use an equality to test for your condition. pattern matching is more expensive than testing for equality.

-You are calling a function named SetMarker that we don't have the definition for. What is this function doing? Writing to DB or file? what else? maybe this function is slow.

Comment: Why didn't I think of profiling? This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. SetMarker sends a string through OLE Automation to a scientific software for data acquisition. I have not been able to find any benchmarks on OLE Automation though.

Comment: Since chosing this answer, I have found the following link to be a good introduction to profiling .NET applications covering various solutions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288073.aspx